# Improving telerik Radgridview Scroller Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, datagridview, telerik

Hello I was trying to Improve the dragging of scroll of the datagrid. It's very slow, Mouse scroll is decent. I was wondering if anyone knows how I can speed this up. I have
`EnableColumnVirtualization="False"`
`EnableRowVirtualization="True"`
Any tips on how abouts i should speed it up?

Comment: post your current XAML. I'm pretty sure you're breaking UI virtualization by putting the DataGrid in an infinite container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only slow while debugging in VS. If you change your build configuration in `Build>Configuration Manager` to `Release` and run the application compiled for release outside of VS it will fly...

Also, in most cases it is best if you don't manually change virtualization settings... allow RadGridView to control virtualization settings on its own and 99.9% of the time that will give you the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your IntelliTrace settings.

Make sure that "IntelliTrace events only" is selected. You may also add a Module filter to ignore IntelliTrace for `*Telerik*`